# Why are my initial WCF calls really slow?

Tags: .net, performance, wcf, silverlight

I'm seeing some weird WCF call timings that I can't explain, and it is causing some real issues in my application. My WCF service calls seem to be taking hundreds of milliseconds if not seconds longer than they should.

I've set up a simple SL5 project hosted in a web app project just to reduce the variables, and I still see terrible timings.

I've got a very simple WCF service call, and I'm using ClientBase to instantiate the service instance, then I'm calling the service in a tight loop 30 times (asynchronously).

The problem is that the first handful of calls take extremely long, according to the IE F12 tools. I'm seeing network times of between 500ms and 2000ms. After that, all of the service call times drop down below 100 ms. The problem for me is that, when I am just calling the service once in an application, I am seeing these initial delays, meaning every time I call the service it tends to take a really long time. I only did the tight loop test to see if things get better over time, which they do.

I would imagine it is doing something like establishing the initial channels, and that is what is taking the hit, and then calls after that just reuse them, but is there anyway to reduce that initial hit? Adding tons of extra time to each of my calls in the real app is killing my performance.

Here is a screenshot of F12 with the call results. You can see the first bunch of calls take an extremely long time, then everything gets nice and quick after:

[image: WCF call screenshot]

Here is the calling code in the test app:

```
Private Sub TestWcfClientBase()
    Dim client = ServicesCommon.GetService()
    client.Proxy.BeginGetCurrentUser((AddressOf OnGetUserCompletedCommon), Nothing)
End Sub

.
.
.

Public Shared Function GetService() As ServiceClient(Of IServiceAsync)
    Dim service As New ServiceClient(Of IServiceAsync)("IServiceAsyncEndpoint")
    Return service
End Function

.
.
.

Public Class ServiceClient(Of T As Class)
    Inherits ClientBase(Of T)
    Implements IDisposable

    Private _disposed As Boolean = False

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(GetType(T).FullName)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(endpointConfigurationName As String)
        MyBase.New(endpointConfigurationName)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Proxy() As T
        Get
            Return Me.Channel
        End Get
    End Property


    Protected Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        If Me.State = CommunicationState.Faulted Then
            MyBase.Abort()
        Else
            Try
            Catch
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

The client config is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding
                name="NoSecurity"
                closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                textEncoding="utf-8">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint
            name="IServiceAsyncEndpoint"
            address="http://localhost/TestService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NoSecurity"
            contract="Services.Interfaces.IServiceAsync" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the stripped down service code:

```
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)>
Public Class TestProxy
    Implements IService

    Public Function GetCurrentUser() As WebUser Implements IServiceAsync.GetCurrentUser
        Dim user As New WebUser
        With user
            .User_Name = "TestUser"
        End With
        Return user
    End Function

End Class
```

And here is the service config:

```
      <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurity" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TestProxyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TestProxyServiceBehavior" name="TestProxy">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurity" contract="Services.Interfaces.IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The longer response time on the first service call is most likely caused by the WCF service spinning up.

Comment: I thought something like that too, but why would it happen every time I refresh the page hosting the Silverlight app? I would have expected the hit only once, but every time I refresh the hosting page I get exactly the same behaviour. Is there some way to confirm this?